# Не могу через g++ собрать .cpp файл в .o

Tags: c++, g++

Всем здравствуйте. Проблема такая: мне нужно использовать нативный код в java, сам код на c++ я писал в visual studio и там он нормально работал, но вот когда пришло время его собирать, мне g++ выкатил много ошибок такого рода:

```
C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include/avxintrin.h:909:1: error: inlining failed in call to 'always_inline' 'void _mm256_storeu_ps(float*, __m256)': target specific option mismatch
  909 | _mm256_storeu_ps (float *__P, __m256 __A)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
MatrMultiply.cpp:27:29: note: called from here
   27 |             _mm256_storeu_ps(c + j + 0, _mm256_setzero_ps());
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Для сборки использовал эту команду:

```
g++ -c -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\include\win32" MatrMultiply.cpp -o MatrMultiply.o
```

Сам фрагмент кода, который, по видимому, и вызывает эти ошибки:

```
void gemm_v2(int M, int N, int K, const float* A, const float* B, float* C)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        float* c = C + i * N;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j += 8)
            _mm256_storeu_ps(c + j + 0, _mm256_setzero_ps());
        for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k)
        {
            const float* b = B + k * N;
            __m256 a = _mm256_set1_ps(A[i * K + k]);
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j += 16)
            {
                _mm256_storeu_ps(c + j + 0, _mm256_fmadd_ps(a,
                                                            _mm256_loadu_ps(b + j + 0), _mm256_loadu_ps(c + j + 0)));
                _mm256_storeu_ps(c + j + 8, _mm256_fmadd_ps(a,
                                                            _mm256_loadu_ps(b + j + 8), _mm256_loadu_ps(c + j + 8)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Что нужно исправить и/или добавить в код и/или команду, чтобы всё это дело успешно собралось и я мог это использовать?)

P.S Пожалуйста без негатива, с нативным кодом, ровно как и с интринсиками имею дело впервые

P.P.S
Полные файлы кода и лог:

.h file - https://pastebin.com/v7C8Jk7W

cpp file - https://pastebin.com/fzjTNQNq

Error - https://pastebin.com/jwjwU9JV

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете функцию которой нет в процессорах целевой архитектуры по умолчанию. Нужно указать опцию архитектуры через опцию компилятора "-m". В данном случае "-mavx".

https://chryswoods.com/vector_c++/immintrin.html

Comment: Странно, но это помогло на половину, остались ошибки с fmaintrin. Помогла сборка с -march=native, но насколько я знаю так делать нехорошо

Comment: Функция с ошибкой в вопросе требует avx вычислительный модуль в процессоре. Следующая функция требует что-то ещё. Лучше посмотреть документацию на неё и указывать только то что нужно для работы.

Comment: Натив не очень хорошо если программа будет переноситься на более слабое железо. Но там есть и другие arch - посмотрите минимальный подходящий шаблон. Коре2дуо вроде покрывал это